# How to solve the integral $\int\frac{{x}}{a + kx^2}dx$

Tags: integration

Given that:

$\int\frac{{1}}{x}dx$ = $lnx + C$
**Correction**: $\int \frac{1}{x} \ dx$ = $\ln |x| + C$

How to calculate the folowing integral ?

$\int\frac{{x}}{a + kx^2}dx$

I read that the answer is :

$\frac{{1}}{2k}ln(a + kx^2)$

But I don't know how to get at this solution. Does someone know how to do it ?

Comment: It should be $\int \frac{1}{x} \ dx = \ln |x| + C$.

Comment: Actually it really should be $\int^x_a \frac{1}{t}dt = \ln(x) + C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the substitution $u = a + kx^2, du = 2kx \ dx$.